# Getting string resources throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, resources, android-context

I have a list of events for specific dates in my calendar.

```
public ArrayList<Event> eventDetails(int m, int d) {

   ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
        switch (m) {
           case 1:
                if (d == 1) {
                    events.add(new Event("Event in Date 1", null, null, null, null, null, null, null));
                }
        }

        return events
}
```

I wanted to convert the hard-coded text to a string resource which I did:

This:

```
events.add(new Event("Event in Date 1", null, null, null, null, null, null, null));
```

To:

```
events.add(new Event(getResources().getString(R.string.text1), null, null, null, null, null, null, null));
```

The problem, however, is that I'm getting a NullPointerException at `getResources().getString(R.string.text1)`.

I realized that I had to pass context to get the String resource, so:

```
_context.getResources().getString(R.string.text1)
```

However, this still threw a NullPointerException. I declared `Context` static but it didn't work.

What is wrong with the code?

**Code:**

```
public class CalendarEvents extends Activity   {
    private static Context _context;

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.events);     
        _context = this.getApplicationContext();

    }


    public ArrayList<Event> eventDetails(int m, int d) {

       ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
            switch (m) {
               case 1:
                    if (d == 1) {
                        events.add(new Event(_context.getResources().getString(R.string.text1), null, null, null, null, null, null, null));
                    }
            }

            return events
    }

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't save the context. Activity extends Context so you always have the context reference you need. Context also has a getString(resourceId) method so you shouldn't have to use getResources(). new Event(getString(R.string.text1), ...) should be sufficient.

Comment: Also if you are using a command-line build did you make sure to do a clean build? Resource changes are not detected by the build system to regenerate the resources.

Comment: Are you sure the null pointer exception is only because of getResources() method?

Comment: But why am I getting `NullPointerException`?

Comment: It can be because of events object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I added a Context parameter to the method and then accessed the resources using the parameter:

```
 public ArrayList<Event> eventDetails(Context mContext, int m, int d) {

 ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
            switch (m) {
               case 1:
                    if (d == 1) {
                        events.add(new Event(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.text1), null, null, null, null, null, null, null));
                    }
            }

            return events
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You missed `()` in `getResources`.

2) Have you defined `R.string.text1` in your resources? (e.g. `res/values/strings.xml`)

Comment: Really? The app wouldn't even compile if he missed the `()` brackets.

Comment: @tolgap He asked what's wrong with the code. Missing the `()` is part of it.

Comment: I'm sorry I just typed that part in the question rather than copy-pasting from the code. `()` is there in the code.

Comment: Yes I have defined `R.string.text1` in `res/values/strings.xml`

Comment: When all simple and obvious parts are eliminated, you need to look into logcat. Look into the stacktrace of your NullPointerException or post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

`String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.mystring);`

`getResources()` is a method of the `Context` class. If you are inside a Activity or a Service (which extend Context) you can use it like in this snippet.